# Disk disappear after fsck

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, disk, fsck

One of my disk is broken after a power failure. When I try to repair my disk by fsck. Firstly it outputs "recovering journal" and "Run journal anyway<y>?

After I press y then fsck outputs:

```
fsck.ext4: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sda
```

And the disk disappear when I check fdisk -l.

I have tried many times, after reboot, the disk will appear and fsck will start recovering journal, after I press y, the disk just disappears.

Any useful suggestions about my situation?

Here are some detail outputs:

```
(anaconda3) ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? yes
fsck.ext4: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Update:
The output of smartctl of sda:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-142-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 2TB
Serial Number:    S5Y3NF0R801831K
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 f4180e30c
Firmware Version: SVT01B6Q
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   Unknown(0x09fc), ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA >3.2 (0x1ff), 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Oct  4 17:22:25 2022 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Read SMART Data failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

Read SMART Log Directory failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

Read SMART Error Log failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

Read SMART Self-test Log failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: First question is to ask why you think you need to run `fsck` at all? Specifically, what are the symptoms of this broken state? (This is _really important_, because for some symptoms the only correct answer is to copy the disk before it fails completely.)

Answer (score 1):

There is almost certainly no filesystem directly on `/dev/sda`.  Read on before you panic.

Usually there is a partition table on a disk, and one or more partitions contain a filesystem. This command will show the partitions on the disk:

parted /dev/sda --align optimal unit MiB print

In my case I have just one, on `/dev/sda1`. Notice the trailing number.

```
Number  Start    End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 1      1.00MiB  49152MiB  49151MiB  primary  ext4
```

If you really need to do so you can now run `fsck` on that partition, but you shouldn't need to do this.

```
e2fsck /dev/sda1
```

However, **before you run any of this**, update your question to show the symptoms of the disk failure that lead you to believe you need to do this at all. For some disk failure modes the only correct response is to copy the disk before it fails completely. Ideally, you'll be able to run SMART diagnostics, and update your question with the output of this:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

Comment: Thank you for your help
1. parted returns:
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input/output error
2. the output of smartctl is updated in the question

Comment: The disk cann't be mounted and the partition table cann't be seen.

Comment: Disk has died. Claim under warranty. I hope you had a backup.